# PHP Login not protecting page

Tags: php, authentication

I know this subject has been covered a ton, and I have looked and searched so I think I am missing something basic.

I have a Username Password log in system that is setup as:

Login page: set to Action - checklogin.php

checklogin.php - checks against the database for username and password, and then in the header brings them to their custom URL, which is in column 3 of the database.  So user1 goes to folder1/, user2 goes to folder2/, etc.

It seems to work fine, but lets say I am logged in as user1 (URL /folder1/), it allows me to enter '/folder2/' in the URL window, and that folders index file comes up.

So basically if I am logged in any username, I can pull up the other users folder/index.php file.

So I think somehow the code on the index.php page is not validating the users correctly.

CODE (top is fine, connecting to DB, etc, so I left that out) :

```
checklogin.php:
// Define $username and $password
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection 
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

 // Register $username, $password and redirect to file "index.php"
session_start();
$_SESSION[$username];
$_SESSION[$password];
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
$_SESSION[$id];
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT folder FROM users2");
$_SESSION['folder'] = $row['folder'];
   if( isset($username) ) {
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
header('Location: clients/'. $row['folder'].'/index.php');
exit();
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
ob_end_flush();
}
?>
```

On the receiving URL index.php page:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true)  {
// not logged in, move to login page
 header("location:../../login.php");
exit;
}
```

I have tried many other variations of the receiving "Protect Page" code, but none seem to work correctly.  Is it the receiving code or the checklogin code??? I feel I am missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance, any take on this will be appreciated. - Randy

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: what is so private on each page different to other users pages

Comment: Something is missing here or out of order. You do `SELECT folder FROM users2` but you never fetch from that result. Instead you do `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` right before it, which is using `$result` from the previous query.

Comment: Validate the path using the `$_SESSION['folder']`

Comment: Thanks njk, I will have to implement that.

Comment: Private because clients have files there.

Comment: Michael, the result does pass, I use it to insert the folder name in the file name string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add additional checks in the protected pages; not only do you need a logged-in user, you also need to check the requested path and see if the user has access to that.

Something like (for example...):

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true 
    || stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SESSION['folder']) === false)  {
// not logged in, move to login page
 header("location:../../login.php");
exit;
}
```

Apart from that you should never store plain-text passwords and you should really switch to PDO (or mysqli) and prepared statements with bound variables.

**Edit:** Another solution to make clear what is happening:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true)  {
  // not logged in, move to login page
  header("location:../../login.php");
  exit();
}
elseif (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SESSION['folder']) === false)
{
  // $_SESSION['folder'] is not found in the path,
  // not user's folder, go to own folder
  header('Location: /clients/'. $_SESSION['folder'].'/index.php');
  exit();
}
else
{
  // show page of user
}
```

Comment: I thought that lets say 'JohnDoe12'= username row1 would be held in the session variable?  So when index.php checks against it the username would have to match??

Comment: jeroen:  That code did not work, so I changed it to below, but it is still allowing another username to access.

Answer (score 0):

your using a lot of unnecessary `!==`
replace most of those with `!=`

also change

```
if($count==1){
```

to

```
while($count>=1){
```

change

```
if( isset($username) ) {
```

to

```
if( isset($username) && $username != "" && $username != NULL ) {
```

`Var_dump` `$result`, make sure it contains what you want, you've got it listed two times.

when you reference a variable inside a session I'd recommend double/single quoting it.

Do yourself a favor and avoid `magic quotes` and `mssql()` entirely. Switch to `pdo` or `MYSQLI`

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) |$_SESSION['loggedin'] !== true)     
if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SESSION['folder']) === false)
 { 
// not logged in, move to login page
 header("location:../../login.php"); exit; } – RandyS just now edit
```

Comment: That does not make sense, the code for second condition is only reached if the user is not logged in. I'll write out a more detailed solution in my answer.